# How to check condition in group by expression?

Tags: sql

I have a database of the following schema (columns):

```
id    phoneNumber    isActive
```

Now, there can be multiple records with the same `phoneNumber`. I would like to check, if for any of the records with the same `phoneNumber`, there exists one that has property `isActive` set to true. If it does, I don't want to see it in the result.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE isActive = 'true' GROUP BY phoneNumber;
```

This doesnt work -> it returns the records even though one has `isActive` set to true

Comment: So if there is one active phone number you do **not** want to see it?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: what is the dialect of SQL? MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT phoneNumber
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY phoneNumber
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN isActive = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Note:  Using `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is not valid SQL and not allowed in almost all databases.  It also shows sloppy thinking.  What should be values be for the columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause?  Those columns should be arguments to aggregation functions, such as `MIN()`, `MAX()`, or `SUM()`.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!

Comment: The only thing I had to change, was '.. isActive = 'true' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END...' as I didn't wanted to include those, which have at least one isActive = true :)

Comment: @uksz: now you will include all that have at least one false. That doesn't mean there can be other rows where the same number is true...

Comment: You are right. It should then be : SUM(CASE WHEN isActive = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;

Comment: @uksz  . . . Yes.  I missed that negative -- that you *don't* want to see it in the result.